# @EnvironmentObject disappearing when used on modal sheet

Tags: swiftui, modal-dialog

There seems to be a bug in #SwiftUI where `@EnvironmentObject` will be no longer available if the user pulls down a modal sheet to close it, but cancels the gesture leaving it open.

Actual error:

> SwiftUI:0: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type  found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for  may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

It doesn't happen all the time, but finding it not too hard to reproduce. Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: You need explicitly inject environment object into sheet content, because it is in different view hierarchy.

Comment: See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658129/12299030.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @Asperi. Could you make that an answer? I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Just append a `.environmentObject(env)` to the presented sheet and it fixes your problem.

In more detail:

```swift
@EnvrironmentObject var currentEnvironment: SomeEnvironment
@State var isSheetPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // ...
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
        OtherView()
            .environmentObject(currentEnvironment)
    }
}
```

To reproduce the issue, you can use the drag gesture to drag the sheet halfway to close it, and just release it. (in a way that it does not close...)

About the situation, I once read that it is somehow a bug. But I also read that this is intended. To me, it seems that it is a bug because the condition that it happens in, feels not right to me.